# Invoke-Expression executing external program and shell script

Tags: powershell, shell, cmd, adb

I'm trying to get the root folder of a connected android device with powershell, when I try the standard command for this in the cmd it just works as expected and returns the path.

**CMD**

```
adb -s <DeviceId> shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

When I try to replicate this command in powershell I get nothing not even an error.

**PowerShell**

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "adb -s <DeviceId> shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE" | Out-String
```

I've searched for some solutions and have found a way to make it work in powershell but I was wondering if their is an other way to get the same result without calling cmd.exe in powershell

**Working PowerShell but seems doggy**

```
(cmd.exe /c adb -s $Id shell echo `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE) | Out-String
```

Comment: Just as an FYI... know that using this cmdlet is not recommended: See: ['invoke-expression is evil'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27invoke-expression+is+evil%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Running exteranl command use PowerShell is well documented. See: [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) See also: [• about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7)

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is not needed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the command as-is.

```
$Result = & adb -s $Id shell echo `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Write-Host $Result
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$Result = & adb "-s $Id shell echo `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE" | Out-String
```

Comment: That won't work, `adb.exe: -s requires an argument` and moving the " before adb results in

`&: The term 'adb -s $Id shell echo ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: try giving full path to adb.exe, like & 'C:\adb\adb.exe'